# FATAL EXCEPTION: main. Error creando un adaptador Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy creando un adaptador y holder por separado para desplegar tres datos en un Recyclerview. Pero al momento de ejecutar el aplicativo me sale un error.

Adaptador:

```
public class AdapterProd extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderProd> {
private ArrayList<ItemsProd> datos;

AdapterProd(ArrayList<ItemsProd> datos){
    this.datos = datos;
}

@Override
public HolderProd onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
    return new HolderProd(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HolderProd holder, int position) {
    holder.etiCodigo.setText(this.datos.get(position).getCodigo());
    holder.etiNombre.setText(this.datos.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.etiValor.setText(this.datos.get(position).getValor());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.datos.size();
}
```

Holder:

```
public class HolderProd extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView etiCodigo,etiNombre,etiValor;


public HolderProd(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    etiCodigo=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prod_cod);
    etiNombre=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prod_nombre);
    etiValor=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prod_precio);
}
```

Clase Registro principal:

```
public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<ItemsProd> listaProd;
    private RecyclerView recycler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
        recycler= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec_prod);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
        ArrayList<ItemsProd> datosProd=new ArrayList<>();
        datosProd.clear();

            for (int i=0; i<50;i++) {
                datosProd.add(new ItemsProd("1","Galleta","0.50"));
            }
        AdapterProd adapter = new AdapterProd(datosProd);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

XML donde creo los TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/prod_precio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="NamespaceTypo">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prod_precio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/prod_precio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prod_nombre"
        android:layout_width="493dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/prod_nombre"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="40dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prod_cod"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/prod_cod" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

El error que me presenta al momento de ejecutar es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tendrias el xml donde creas los textviews?

Comment: Hola Gaston, lo acabo de incluir en la pregunta.

Comment: Tu RelativeLayout tiene el mismo id que un TextView :   android:id="@+id/prod_precio" al tratar de obtener la referencia y "convertir" este RelativeLayout a TextView es lo que esta provocando el problema, cambia el id de tu RelativeLayout, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes 2 widget con el mismo id en este caso el `TextView` y el `RelativeLayout` tienen el siguiente id `android:id="@+id/prod_precio"`

Solamente cambia el id de alguno de los 2 widgets

Espero te sea de utilidad saludos.

Answer (score 0):

[**`ClassCastException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassCastException) se refiere a que estas intentando convertir una clase de un tipo a otro tipo del cual no hay una relación de herencia entre ambas.

En este caso estas obteniendo la referencia de un `TextView` con id `prod_precio` ...

```
 etiValor=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prod_precio);
```

...pero **en tu layout además de un `TextView` con id `prod_precio` existe un `RelativeLayout` con el mismo id el cual esta tratando de definir como `TextView`!**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/prod_precio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="NamespaceTypo">
```

**Cambia el id de tu `RelativeLayout` para que no provoque este problema.** Por ejemplo `layout_registro`, puedes también no asignar un id a este layout si no lo necesitas :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/layout_registro"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="NamespaceTypo">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prod_precio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/prod_precio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prod_nombre"
        android:layout_width="493dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/prod_nombre"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="40dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prod_cod"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/prod_cod" />

</RelativeLayout>
```